# React MaterialUI - ExpansionPanelSummary - Add counter to div id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I need a functionality that can **add a counter to the div id** whenever the **render function** is called. The purpose is to have unique div's.

Here is my render function -

```
render() {

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            {
                someFunction.map(output => {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <ExpansionPanel key={output.someKey} defaultExpanded={shouldExpand}>
                                <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon/>} >
                                    <div id="Kirti">
                                        <span>{output.someKey}</span>
                                        <span>"SomeText"</span>
                                    </div>
                                </ExpansionPanelSummary>
                                <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                                    <div> 
                                        {"Some Detail"}
                                    </div>
                                </ExpansionPanelDetails>
                            </ExpansionPanel>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

I need to add a counter to div id="Kirti". Something like

1. int count = 0;
2. Call render function.
3. `<div id=("Kirti"+count)>`
4. count++

Since I can have multiple div's with id (starting with) "Kirti", I need to make them unique by adding this counter.

If there is any more info required for better understanding of this issue, please let me know.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function has an index/counter that's passed on to the function callback.

So what you want to do is:

```
{someFunction.map((output, index) =>
  <ExpansionPanel key={output.someKey} id={`panel-${index}`}>
    // more components here...
  </ExpansionPanel>
)}
```